# How to make let rec n read read_int in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

The objective of this code is to given a number realise multiple operations until the number is equal to 42. I'm not being able to make let rec read read_int

```
let n = read_int ()
let rec check n =
    if n < 42 then begin Printf.printf "bad luck" end
    else if n = 42 then begin Printf.printf "u win" end
    else if n mod 5 = 0 then begin check (n - 42) end
```

Comment: can be more precise on what is your issue?

Comment: A quick thought: your function `check` isn't exhaustive. What happens if the `n` parameter into the function is `43`? Well, that isn't less than 42. It isn't equal to 42. And it isn't evenly divisible by 5. Maybe you do intend for nothing to happen, but you should be explicit about that.

Answer (score 0):

- you don't need to have `begin`/`end` when you only have a single expression
- if you want to call `read_int` each time you call `check`, then:

  1. `check` does not need to accept a parameter `n`
  2. you have to call `read_int ()` inside the body of `check`
- if however you want to call `check` with a value initially read from standard input, then passed by recursive invocations of `check`, then you need:

  1. a purely functional (recursive) function `check` accepting a parameter `n`
  2. another function `check_input` that reads standard input and pass the value to `check`